# jQuery - Loading images from xml not working in chrome

Tags: jquery, xml, image, google-chrome

I'm trying to load images onto the screen based on a XML. Here is the xml I'm using

```
<item>
    <heading>Heading 1</heading>
    <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla tempus   varius. Nulla facilisi. In nisi leo, commodo id vestibulum non, mollis quis justo. Nunc elementum feugiat gravida. Praesent condimentum nisi id sapien placerat sed posuere velit fringilla. Curabitur ac purus odio. </content>
    <image>image.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
   <heading>Heading 2</heading>
   <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla tempus varius. Nulla facilisi. In nisi leo, commodo id vestibulum non, mollis quis justo. Nunc elementum feugiat gravida. Praesent condimentum nisi id sapien placerat sed posuere velit fringilla. Curabitur ac purus odio. </content>
   <image>image.jpg</image>
</item>
```

And I'm retrieving the elements with jQuery like this.

```
$.get('feed1.xml', function(xml) {
     $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
     content+= "\<li class=\"paginate\"\>";
     content+= '\<img src=\"' + $(this).find('image').text() + '\"\/\>';
     content+= "\<h3\>" + $(this).find('heading').text() + "\<\/h3\>" ;
     content+= "\<p\>" + $(this).find('content').text() + "\<\/p\>";
     content+="\<\/li\>";
 });
```

This works well in Firefox. However in Chrome and IE the 'heading' and 'content' loads as expected but the image part returns an empty string. I debugged a little and noticed that the same code works in Chrome if I just change the element name 'image' to something else. Then I did a little console.log to understand what's happening in the background.

```
 $(xml).find('item').children().each(function(){
   console.log((this).nodeName);
 });
```

This returned,

```
HEADING
CONTENT
IMG
```

in chrome while FF retained the element names.

I also tried changing the source code to this
       content+= '\';

But this didn't work either.

Any ideas why Chrome changes the element name 'image' to 'img'? Also, why is it not able to locate the object 'img' when it is present in the DOM?

Comment: image is not a valid tag name, img is. Its seems like your xml is parsed to html.

Comment: I don't see any specific XML rule disqualifying the <image> tag in the w3 spec. Even if we assume that to be right for a minute, the image should have loaded when I used    find('img').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try telling it what dataType to expect.

```
$.get('feed1.xml', function(xml) {
     $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
     content+= "\<li class=\"paginate\"\>";
     content+= '\<img src=\"' + $(this).find('image').text() + '\"\/\>';
     content+= "\<h3\>" + $(this).find('heading').text() + "\<\/h3\>" ;
     content+= "\<p\>" + $(this).find('content').text() + "\<\/p\>";
     content+="\<\/li\>";
 }, dataType: "xml");
```

The jQuery `get` function is shorthand for the `ajax` function.  I'm guessing that in the guts of jQuery, the chrome implementation is guessing the type of document to be html and not xml and maybe replaces the "image" with "img".

Comment: Actually no. jQuery documentation says it can intelligently identify HTML XML, json and strings from one another. Nevertheless I've tried it out and it still doesn't work. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with the issue for others to troubleshoot?

Comment: The XML is over here, http://www.skmvasu.com/feed1.xml incase you need to take a look.

Comment: The jsfiddle won't work because of cross site limits.  I also you noticed you use a single quote on the line where you build the image tag.  I wonder if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Explicitly specifying the datatype works as you had suggested. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried same example and found problem in your xml .

XML file must be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hello>
<item>
    <heading>Heading 1</heading>
    <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla tempus   varius. Nulla facilisi. In nisi leo, commodo id vestibulum non, mollis quis justo. Nunc elementum feugiat gravida. Praesent condimentum nisi id sapien placerat sed posuere velit fringilla. Curabitur ac purus odio. </content>
    <image>image.jpg</image>
</item>
<item>
   <heading>Heading 2</heading>
   <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla tempus varius. Nulla facilisi. In nisi leo, commodo id vestibulum non, mollis quis justo. Nunc elementum feugiat gravida. Praesent condimentum nisi id sapien placerat sed posuere velit fringilla. Curabitur ac purus odio. </content>
   <image>image.jpg</image>
</item>
</hello>
```

So your jquery code works fine...

If you have still problem then you can use this

```
$.get('feed1.xml', function(xml) {
         $(xml).find('item').each(function() {
         content+= "<li class='paginate'>";
         content+= "<img src='" + $(this).find("image").text() + "'/>";
         content+= "<h3>" + $(this).find("heading").text() + "</h3>" ;
         content+= "<p>" + $(this).find("content").text() + "</p>";
         content+="</li>";
     });
```

Comment: The item elements are enclosed properly within another top level element. I had just pasted a partial of my original file just to show the document structure.